# How to add a dynamically created node(tag) at the desired location?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Suppose I have two DIVs on my page.

```
<body>
<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
</body>
```

I want to create a new DIV dynamically using JavaScript and place it between *d1* and *d2*. If I use the `appendChild` method the new DIV is placed at the end.

Right now I can only think of paring the `innerHTML` of the BODY and appending the new DIV at the desired location. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/insertBefore)

```
document.body.insertBefore( 
    newNode, 
    document.getElementById('d2') 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the [`Node.insertBefore` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore) to insert a node before another:

```
var newNode = document.createElement("div"),
    d2 = document.getElementById("d2");
d2.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, d2);
```

Comment: I should have referred the DOM before asking. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For DOM manipulation , jQuery API offers various helpful methods.Following are some of them :-

insertBefore() , insertAfter() , append() , appendTo() , prepend() , prependTo() etc . These functions provide more control over insertion of DOM elements at specific locations in web page.